# letsencrypt-win-simple checking renewals doesnt find all sites

Tags: windows, webserver, letsencrypt

I had a certificate renewal that should have happen automatically but it did not. I tried to run the scheduled task manually so running `letsencrypt.exe --renew --baseuri "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/"` but it did not find the domain I thought it would. It only listed some of my other secures domains.

I run letsencrypt-win-simple v.1.9.1.

What can I do to make it renew the missing domain as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets encrypt stores information about what domains it should check for renew in Windows registry. It is located in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\letsencrypt-win-simple\https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/Renewals`.

Open the registry setting and add your missing domain to the list. Every domain is on a new row and hopefully you have another domain listed using much the same settings so you can easily copy and edit it.

**Don't forget to set the date of the renewal entry to a date that has passed!**

I had success doing this and next renewal check the certificate was renewed.